# getting reference to element in kendo auto complete

Tags: kendo-ui

I am calling a function on onselect event of a kendo auto complete. I want to get reference to the element on which kendo auto complete property is applied. I have 4 auto complete with same data source. I want to show a loading image on this elements when search is in progress. How do i get the reference to this elements ? How do I know, from which auto complete element onSelect is called? Please help me

```
$("#pmt_apply_order1").kendoAutoComplete({ 

      select: onSelect,

});
$("#pmt_apply_order2").kendoAutoComplete({ 

      select: onSelect,

});

 function onSelect(e) { 

   // I want reference to  $("#pmt_apply_order1") when selects from $("#pmt_apply_order1")           

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the reference of the parent element using **this.element** inside the onSelect event .
To see get the id of the parent auto complete element, u need to use **this.element.attr("id")**.
You can see a full demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FVQkG/

```
                function onSelect(e) {

               alert("id of parent auto complete: " + this.element.attr("id"));
                        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());

                }
```

Comment: But I have same problem in requestStart option of auto complete. Here I am calling a function loadingImage(). In this function I am not getting the reference as you mentioned. How can I do this?

Comment: requestStart is an event of the DataSource and not of autocomplete. So may be u can wire the onfocus js event on your auto complete input elements and save the current focused autocomplete's id in a variable. now on requestStart event of the DataSource, you can display the animation on this input element.

Comment: I have a question! How we can know this.element is a jquery object so that we can use attr method. Is there any tool for it like chrome console.

Comment: just chekc if this.element is null or undefined. otherwise its a JS object.